# OpenGL md3 models and shaders

Tags: opengl, model, shader

I tries to load some trees to my game.

I am already using md3 models so I found some md3 tree models here: http://www.custommapmakers.org/wiki/index.php/Models:GR_Trees_set

It easy to load easy model model alone(w/o textures) but, there is shader file and I have no idea how I should use it.

Can I get some advices how to write shader loader and assign textures to trees with that?

Comment: You might have more luck asking on the Game Dev Stack Exchange.  Isn't an MD3 file fairly Quake exclusive?  Loading models isn't that hard since vertex/geometry can be interpreted fairly easily.  However, unless the shaders are written in something like GLSL or HLSL I'm not sure how to get them loaded without knowing the Quake shader setup.  Is this for your own engine or are you actually putting this into Quake?

Comment: Thanks, a lot I will try my luck there and I am going to use this in my own engine.